# Navigation bar does not update when popping out to root view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a story board set up like this:

1. Navigation Controller --- connected to ---> View A ---> table cell segue ---> View B
2. Standalone View C, that is, there is no segue connected to it from any other view in the storyboard.

I tap on a cell in View A, that automatically performs segue to View B.
In View B, after the view is shown and an application event is triggered, it automatically dismisses itself and pushes an instance of View C, doing something like this:

View B:

```
- (void)someEvent
{
    ViewCController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

That works all great, View C pops into view. However, when I tap the "back" button on the navigation bar of View C, I want it to pop all the way back to View A, not View B. I tried this:

View C:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
     [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

That works almost as expected in that View C is dismissed and View A comes back up bypassing View B. Problem is, the navigation bar in View A still thinks it's one level deeper because it still shows the "Back" button and not the ones in View A. I have to tap the "Back" button again for it to show the correct buttons.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do this, or that you should do this. The back button has a specific purpose -- to go back to the previous view controller, and I don't think you should try to subvert that (its title is going to be point to that one, not your first one). It would be better to add another bar button to the navigation bar in viewC, and have that connected to code that does popToRootViewController.

Comment: +1 I agree. Obviously, the second controller could set its back button (the button that appears as the "back" button on the third controller) to say whatever you want, but that doesn't change the fact of your root observation, that it's not a great experience to have a back button that doesn't really take you back one controller, but rather two.

Comment: I see your point. But, it depends on the context of the application. Say ViewB is transitional only, it performs some set up operation or connection that may or may not succeed. If it does succeed, then it transfer the spotlight to ViewC. Once you're done with it, there is little use going back to the transitional view. Having said that, I suppose another approach would be to use the transitional view on the way back to clean up, etc before going back to the root controller. Thanks for the feedback in any event.

Comment: @LuisArtola, if you don't want users to go back to the previous screen, you can hide the back button, leaving only the new button added to go back to the root.

Answer (score 1):

In View C alloc your own barButtonItem and put it in `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to replace the back button and have the action of this button do `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Comment: Agreed. You end up with a slightly weird UX, where the you see the "real" back button slide off behind the new one that pops up in it's place with non-back-button shape, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly works. The only caveat is that the button no longer looks like a "back" button, i.e. its left side is not angled, but straight.

Comment: make your own custom arrow shaped button in photoshop